# Rendering dynamic checkbox elements to 3 every row with pug template

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, pug

I need to render a dynamic set of checkbox elements with the pug template on my Express JS web app.

I am with the Bootstrap styling with the pug template. How to render the checkboxes depends on the variable `approvedUsersArr` (in the JS Array type) passed into the pug template. An element in `approvedUsersArr` is a JS Object that has `objectId` and `approved_user` as attributes.

Basically I want every row has three checkboxes. When a row is filled with three checkboxes in columns, it starts a new row and starts to render another set of three checkboxes, and so forth.

My snippet of pug looks like below.

```
.modal-body.h-100
    each au, index in approvedUsersArr
        if (index + 1) % 3 == 1
            .row
                .col-md-4
                    .custom-control.custom-checkbox
                        input.custom-control-input(type='checkbox' value=au.objectId id='chbApprovedUser_' + au.objectId)
                        label.custom-control-label(for='chbApprovedUser_' + au.objectId) #{au.approved_user}
        else
                .col-md-4
                    .custom-control.custom-checkbox
                        input.custom-control-input(type='checkbox' value=au.objectId id='chbApprovedUser_' + au.objectId)
                        label.custom-control-label(for='chbApprovedUser_' + au.objectId) #{au.approved_user}
```

It is rendered like below which is incorrect.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the `.row` element outside your if statement:

```
.modal-body.h-100
  each au, index in approvedUsersArr
    .row
      if (index + 1) % 3 == 1
        .col-md-4
          .custom-control.custom-checkbox
            input.custom-control-input(type='checkbox' value=au.objectId id='chbApprovedUser_' + au.objectId)
            label.custom-control-label(for='chbApprovedUser_' + au.objectId) #{au.approved_user}
      else
        .col-md-4
          .custom-control.custom-checkbox
            input.custom-control-input(type='checkbox' value=au.objectId id='chbApprovedUser_' + au.objectId)
            label.custom-control-label(for='chbApprovedUser_' + au.objectId) #{au.approved_user}
```

As a footnote, it took a few times reading through your question to understand exactly what your issue was.  I'd recommend that in future you start your questions with a clear statement of what exactly is the issue.